# ColdFusion could not delete the file for an unknown reason

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to delete and recreate a test file, but am getting the error below. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**Error:**

```
ColdFusion could not delete the file e:\sample\test2.html for an unknown reason.
```

**Code:**

```
<cfif FileExists("e:\sample\test2.html")>
   <cffile action="delete"file="e:\sample\test2.html"><br>
   <p>deleted the file </p>
<cfelse>
   <p>Sorry, can't delete the file - it doesn't exist.</p>
</cfif>

<cfset createObject("java", "java.lang.Thread").sleep(JavaCast("int", 90000))>
<cfsavecontent variable="HTML">
    <cfinclude template="noticeEmail.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>        

<cffile action="WRITE"  attributes = "normal" nameconflict="Overwrite"  
      file="e:\sample\test2.html" output="#HTML#">
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your error, but the `nameconflict` attribute does not apply to `action="write"`, only uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would check is permissions for the user that ColdFusion is running as.
I don't know how you're running CF or in what sort of environment you're on but assuming that this is a local development environment, are on a windows machine and are running ColdFusion as a service:

- Find the ColdFusion service in the services manager (start -> run ->
  services.msc)
- Right click on the ColdFusion Service and look in the log on tab to find "who this is running as. (the service could be named several things depending on how it is installed but
  look for "ColdFusion 9 Application Server", Anything starting with
  JRun or Macromedia)
- If this isn't local system then you'll need to confirm that the user has read / write access to e:\sample\test2.html

Other things that could cause errors, could another program have this file locked, what is happening with the file after it is created (is it only created through ColdFusion)

Also could you post the actual error that you are receiving?
If it's "Sorry, can't delete the file - it doesn't exist." Then this is due to the check you've got at the top to confirm if the file exists.

Finally the code that you've pasted above appears to have the first character missing from every line, it would be worth fixing this so that others can more easily copy and paste the code.

Comment: Fyi, post modified to add back missing characters.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and as it turns out the file was locked, because CF was still uploading it, when I went to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, though none of the answers I found applied. Although my file passed the FileExists test, it still failed the actual delete.  I was building the filename  using variables:

```
<cfset sFilename = REQUEST.SubscriberWebFiles
                        & form.SubscriberID & "\Attachments\" 
                        & qryAttachmentsTrash.AttachmentName>
```

I wrapped the code with a Trim:

```
<cfset sFilename = Trim(REQUEST.SubscriberWebFiles
                       & form.SubscriberID & "\Attachments\" 
                       & qryAttachmentsTrash.AttachmentName)>
```

and the problem magically disappeared!

Comment: I tried that too and yes, my problem also went away magically!! Weird, but there you go. Using directoryDelete() on CF10 on Win7 Pro. I did notice, however, that if clicked on one of the files in the directory, (not open it), then clicked on a file in another folder altogether, my directoryDelete() failed with the unknown error the first time, but then executing directoryDelete() then directoryCreate() subsequent times all worked flawlessly as long as I used Trim(). Without Trim() I got persistent "unknown errors" with the same test. FYI.

Comment: i.e. by "the same test" I mean repeatedly create and delete the folder (recursively)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to delete an MS Word document with ColdFusion

```
<cfif FileExists( WordFilePath &".doc")>
   <cffile action="delete"
       file="#WordFilePath#.doc">
<cfelse>
    Sorry, can't delete the file - it doesn't exist.
</cfif>
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what he is doing already :) But the file is locked, for some reason, so the delete fails. Also, your code snippet was missing the opening `<` symbol (now fixed). To post CFML snippets, just use the code sample option ie "{}"

Answer (score 0):

Your web server/os might be holding onto the file.  Can you try creating the file without opening it and see if you delete it then?  So just create a file, and then delete it right away.